# CKEditor doesn't work only in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, sprockets, uglifier

I'm using the [`ckeditor`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) ruby gem (v4.2.2) in my Rails app and it works fine in development but not in my `production` environment. It doesn't look like a problem with my Asset Pipeline because all other assets load without any issues.

On the page, Google Chrome gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

[image]

while Firefox just throws this in the console:

```
TypeError: c[a] is undefined[Learn More]
```

---

### **What I've tried so far:**

- Use `Uglifier.new(mangle: false)` as the JS Compressor in Sprockets
- Manually set `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH`

The asset files generated by `rake asset:precompile` in `public/assets/ckeditor` all have a hash at the end like this:

```
ckeditor-e0b9bfe15298d2b2dd388960b27d35e6a18c89b2390f8986d398c30da5496e4b.js
config-1fb318e1cc0eea7b8c181941c3c1f09d2b96107b2f7ff4891755fbb2201ba53d.js
contents-4540cf2cb7116b32bac2995494c4fc0c55804444f37c02cfa11256bd695e4194.css
# etc
```

but the JS doesn't seem to be loading them and trying to fix that now.

---

#### Code

My Javascript File:

```
//= require pages-javascript
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree ./ckeditor
//= require_self
```

Assets Initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |filename, full_path|
  if filename =~ /\.(css|js|svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_s
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      Rails.logger.info "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      Rails.logger.info "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

Comment: I see you prepared a manifest file for ckeditor specifically, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the Library [Issues and Pull Requests](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/) on Github, turns out it wasn't an issue with my code but a bug in the `4.x.x` versions of the Ruby Gem itself (causing incompatibilities with `Rails 5`).

Someone already [**opened an issue**](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/719) and a [**PR fixing this was also merged**](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/716) to master 2 months ago, but there were no releases after it containing the patch. So my temporary solution is to load the gem directly from master:

```
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor', ref: '11d3a5b'
```

Comment: And wasted 10+ hours trying to 'fix' this.

Comment: I had this issue on 4.2.2. Updating to 4.2.4 solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to load the ckeditor separately? Try to load it without your bundling to see If the library is loading correctly. From the console output I see that some files are not loaded, probably the bundling/minification doesn't work as it should be for those files. Load the ckeditor files in the `<head>` to see if that way everything works.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, it works normally. This is an issue with how assets are compressed in production and the frontend client is unable to load them.

Comment: So just separate the ckeditor from your bundling. I almost every time separate the external libraries from my bundling because they gives me an errors and headaches. You never know how those libraries are implemented.